# Which one is faster in SQL ... LIKE s_______ or ... LIKE s%

Tags: mysql, sql

Which one is faster in SQL ... LIKE s_______ or ... LIKE s%

Comment: what do you think which one will be faster, did you tried with sample data. this question is too broad.

Comment: Why not [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?

Comment: index helps to make things faster not the condition alone.
No sample data, we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

These conditions:

```
<col> LIKE 's_______'
<col> LIKE 's%'
```

do different things.  The first returns values that are exactly 8 characters and start with `'s'`.  The second returns strings that start with `'s'` and have any length.

You should use the version that matches the logic you want to implement.  From the perspective of readability, the second is simpler.  I would imagine that checking for a length of exactly 8 adds some overhead.  However, that would be minimal compared to the effort to read and process the table.